# How to get broadcast connect without cam in pubnub webrtc lib?

Tags: webrtc, webcam, broadcast, pubnub, videocall

How are you. 
I have followed tutorial for broadcasting here.
https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/tree/master/tutorials
It work well, but viewer.html don't get broadcaster's video if viewer has no webcam.

The problem is `broadcaster.connected` function not being called (but `phone.receive` called)

```
phone.receive(function(broadcaster){
        console.log("Fetching broadcaster's video");

        // Display Your Friend's Live Video
        broadcaster.connected( broadcaster => {
            if (playing) return;
            playing = true;
            console.log("Playing broadcaster's video");
            phone.$('video-out').appendChild(broadcaster.video);
            setTimeout( () => phone.camera.stop(), 1000 );
        });

        broadcaster.ended( broadcaster => console.log('Stream ended') );
    });
```

I have tested multiple times, and it only works when viewer side has cam.

I want viewer can see broadcaster without cam or audio input.
How to configure this?

Thanks

Comment: Some updates were added: https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk/commit/89da1078993d527ca954dd662365a6ea3bea6371#diff-6e9b5d15f3341afc2c4dde2b5368eadaR64-R66